# Firebase custom events don't show up in the dashboard

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I would like to create an event in firebase to see how many users make use of the Facebook share feature. So I created these events like this:

```
import Firebase

Analytics.logEvent("Facebook Share Successful!", parameters: ["user_id": username])
Analytics.logEvent("Facebook Share Cancelled!", parameters: ["user_id": username])
```

But in Firebase dashboard, I'm not able to see the event listed. I have waited for more than 24 hours too. Is there anything else I need to do that I have missed?

**UPDATE**

After Misbah's suggestion to include the debug mode, I'm able to find the event, however, it is logged under error.

It doesn't like the space/exclamation mark in the naming. The screenshot shows error 2.

> 2 Event name is invalid (empty, too long, invalid characters) Name of
>   the invalid event The event is ignored and a firebase_error event is
>   logged with a firebase_error_value parameter which indicates the
>   invalid event name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to enable debug mode and track events on debugView ?

> To enable Analytics Debug mode on your development device, specify the
>   following command line argument in Xcode :
>
> -FIRDebugEnabled
>
> This behavior persists until you explicitly disable Debug mode by
>   specifying the following command line argument :
>
> -FIRDebugDisabled

More informations here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview